# alert notification on android

Tags: android, trigger.io

Is it possibile to use forge.notification.create() or similar to show an alert-like message on android devices. On ios it's working like this but on android it is showing a message on top of the view.
thanks

Comment: I would love it if Trigger.io Forge made native equivalents to .alert() and .confirm() in Javascript. Perhaps someone could build these simply as a plugin?

Comment: The one plugin that is by default already included in the inspector projects given by Trigger.io is actually doing that: native alert() exposed to javascript. See the [docs](http://docs.trigger.io/en/latest/modules/native/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Native alerts, confirms and toast messages were included in Forge v1.4.39.

```
forge.notification.alert('My Title: Alert', 'My Body: Alert');
```

[image]

---

```
forge.notification.confirm("My Title: Confirm", "My Body: Confirm", "Y", "N", 
    function (userClickedYes) {
      if (userClickedYes) {
        // ... implement logic for when user clicked "Y"
      } else {
        // ... implement logic for when user clicked "N"
      }
});
```

[image]

---

```
forge.notification.toast('My Body: Toast');
```

[image]

---

See the [notification docs](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/modules/notification.html) for more information.